# Folder.selectDialog different behaviour on Mac and Windows

Tags: scripting, adobe, adobe-scriptui

My problem is when I select the folder using the following code, the behaviour of the `selectDialog` is different on Mac and Windows. On Mac, the finder window that comes up shows files in present in the folder but on Windows it does not show files in the folder. Is it possible to show files present in the folder while choosing the path using below code or in different way on Windows?

```
Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder to save the files");
```

I have attached the screen shot for Mac and Windows

**Mac**

[image]
Here it shows files and folders present in the folder

**Windows**

[image]

Here it only shows folders even files are present in this folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, it is OS dependent behaviour.